# Java select object instance based on variable

Tags: java, object

I have a really annoying assignment which requires me to create 3 instances of a object and I need to create methods to modify and access them for use in another class.
I know the simplest and best way to do this would be to use an array, but I'm not supposed to know about those yet and the assignment requires I NOT use them.

So basically I'm looking for a way to interact with each of the objects based on another variable.

For example I have the following instances of my object:

object1
object2
object3

What I want to be able to do is create a variable objectNo, and use the number of that variable to select object 1, 2 or 3

Instead of having a bunch of if statements and writing the same code 3 times where the only difference is the object name as I have it currently below:

```
public void updateObject (int argNo, String argName)
{
private int objectNo = argNo;
private String productName = argName;
if (objectNo == 1)
    {
        object1.name = productName

    }

else if (objectNo == 2)
    {
        object2.name = productName
        ...
    }
```

Any suggestions, I'm new to Java and this is doing my head in.

Comment: If it's an assignment, and you haven't learned about Arrays or Maps or other data structures, it may be the point of the assignment to use conditionals.

Comment: There are plenty of other conditionals already in the assignment.  As far as I can determine the purpose of the assignment is to demonstrate understanding of objects and methods

Comment: I just hate having lots of unnecessary code when there should be a better way

Comment: An array or other data structure like `Map` is the way you will normally do this. If you can't use arrays then you have to use `if...else` or `switch`.

Comment: Can you just add a property in the object to key off or can you not edit the object you're testing?

Comment: I've never seen access modifiers (the "private" ones) used within a method, you should probably remove those. If those variables need to have class scope, you can put them after the class declaration and then use access modifiers. Just a heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Instead of having a bunch of if statements and writing the same code 3 times where the only difference is the object name as I have it currently below:

If you want to save yourself from copy & pasting code you can use a variable in this case, for example:

```
MyObject objectToChange;

if (objectNo == 1) {
    objectToChange = object1;
} else if (objectNo == 2) {
    objectToChange = object2;
} else if (objectNo == 3) {
    objectToChange = object3;
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(Integer.toString(objectNo));
}

objectToChange.name = productName;
```

Whether this actually helps you out depends on how much stuff you're doing with `objectToChange`.

You also could use a `switch` instead of `if...else` but it doesn't really save you anything except making the code line up neatly.

Of course an array or `Map` is the correct way to do something like this in the real world.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what I'm looking for!
I'll see if I can implement this

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

```
if (objectNo = 1)
```

That assigns the value 1 to `objectNo` and then tries to evaluate `objectNo` as a boolean which will throw an error at compile because `objectNo` is an int not a boolean. Should be

```
if (objectNo == 1)
```

[Switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement can cut down on verbosity of if-else

```
switch (objectNo) {
    case 1: object1.setName(productName);
        break;
    case 2: object2.setName(productName);
        break;
    case 3: object3.setName(productName);
        break;
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot handle " + objectNo);
}
```

But as you indicated a more elegant solution is to use an array.

```
new X[] {object1, object2, object3, ...}[objectNo].setName(productName);
```

Third, as shown above, you should create a setter for name, you shouldn't expose fields in an object to other classes, and you should mark them as private.

Comment: Yeah, I realised I made a few coding errors in the original question, will fix them up.
I had just come out of a mid term so my brain was a bit muffled when I posted it!

Answer (score 0):

...if you make an array of the objects you instanced in the first time, you can select which one to call by changing your [ ] content.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyClass {


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        createObject(1, "String");
        createObject(2, "StringBuffer");
        createObject(3, "StringBuilder");

    }


    public static void createObject(int argNo, String argName)
    {
        Object user=null;
        if(argNo==1)
        {
            user=new String();

        }
        else if(argNo==2)
        {
            user=new StringBuffer();


        }else if(argNo==3)
        {
            user=new StringBuilder();

        }

        System.out.println("Object of type "+user.getClass()+" created");
    }

}
```

Comment: This one would be out of scope for my current assignment, extending classes etc not in scope.